# Modprobe blacklisting using kernel command line

Tags: linux, nvidia, kernel-modules, modprobe, nouveau

I have two boot configurations which more or less look like this:

1. `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau`
2. `modprobe.blacklist=nvidia,<and other nvidia modules>`

Which serve to dynamically use the open source or proprietary driver when booting. Now I want to add another boot entry which disables both `nouveau` and `nvidia` in effect disabling the NVIDIA GPU.

3. `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau,nvidia,...`

`lsmod | grep -iE '(nouveau|nvidia)'` still shows `nvidia` so my guess is that another module pulls that in.

Normally I could create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`:

```
install nvidia /bin/true
install nouveau /bin/true
```

But this would mean that I loose the lexibility of just choosing another boot entry.

Is there any way this behavior could be achieved? My only idea was to have two small filesystems which contain different `modprobe.d` configurations and mount them dynamically as early as possible during the boot process after changing to the real root partition.

Comment: I'm a donkey the parameter is `module_blacklist=...` instead of `modprobe.blacklist=...`